# Update Row/Column in an AWS Glue Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue table that uses an S3 bucket as it's location. How can I update a specific row/column with new values?

It is my understanding that AWS Athena is Read Only and thus cannot perform this action so I am looking for a different way to do so.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Recently, AWS Athena introduced support of [`INSERT INTO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html) statement. I haven't tried it out yet, but looks like what you are after